# Why isn't GNUPlot drawing a trendline that's fitted to the points in my dataset?

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following GNUPlot sequence of commands:

```
$ cat bb.gnuplot
set datafile separator ","
set autoscale x
set autoscale y
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y%m%d"
set format x "%Y%m%d"
set key left top
set grid
m=1
b=1
f(x) = m*x + b
fit f(x) "bb" using 1:2 via m,b
plot "bb" using 1:2 title "filebeat-6.5.1", f(x) title "fit"
```

Along with this sample data:

```
$ cat bb
20190416,0
20190417,0
20190418,0
20190419,0
20190420,0
20190423,0
20190424,0
20190425,0
20190426,0
20190509,0
20190510,72
20190511,62
20190512,63
20190513,108
20190514,78
20190515,66
20190516,59
20190517,86
20190518,57
20190519,57
20190520,62
20190521,78
20190522,95
20190523,104
20190524,22
20190525,128
20190526,96
20190527,125
20190528,129
20190529,152
20190530,160
20190531,148
20190601,136
20190602,178
20190603,198
20190604,148
20190605,140
20190606,142
20190607,171
20190608,205
20190609,174
20190610,198
20190611,208
20190612,205
20190613,13
```

I'm trying to get GNUPlot to draw a trend line in the same plot but the line I'm getting doesn't make sense to me in terms of where it's getting placed in my plot.

```
$  gnuplot < bb.gnuplot
iter      chisq       delta/lim  lambda   m             b
   0 1.0926745428e+20   0.00e+00  1.10e+09    1.000000e+00   1.000000e+00
   1 1.3194958855e+16  -8.28e+08  1.10e+08    1.098907e-02   1.000000e+00
   2 1.6307478323e+08  -8.09e+12  1.10e+07    1.279057e-06   1.000000e+00
   3 2.1025098835e+05  -7.75e+07  1.10e+06    5.819285e-08   1.000000e+00
   4 2.1025098815e+05  -9.56e-05  1.10e+05    5.819150e-08   1.000000e+00
iter      chisq       delta/lim  lambda   m             b

After 4 iterations the fit converged.
final sum of squares of residuals : 210251
rel. change during last iteration : -9.56318e-10

degrees of freedom    (FIT_NDF)                        : 43
rms of residuals      (FIT_STDFIT) = sqrt(WSSR/ndf)    : 69.9254
variance of residuals (reduced chisquare) = WSSR/ndf   : 4889.56

Final set of parameters            Asymptotic Standard Error
=======================            ==========================
m               = 5.81915e-08      +/- 7.064e-06    (1.214e+04%)
b               = 1                +/- 1.101e+04    (1.101e+06%)

correlation matrix of the fit parameters:
                m      b
m               1.000
b              -1.000  1.000
```

Resulting graph:

[image]

I'm expecting the line to cut through my points and show me the optimally fitted line among the data points that I've provided it.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find the appropriate section in the manual and I can't explain it well but
exchange your function with:

```
f(x) = m*(x-strptime("%Y%m%d","20190509")) + b
```

I guess it has something to do with offset/prescaling and because time/date data is handled internally as seconds passed from January, 1st 1970. So, today, June, 13th 2019 is approx. 1'560'000'000 seconds. And your time span is only about 4'580'000 seconds This makes it difficult to find proper parameters. If I find a better explanation, I will add it (or maybe somebody else can explain better).

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Interesting. I read something about this and tried it a few ways but never this particular example. I took it as having something to do with the fit function itself. Your solution fixes my issue, thanks BTW.